# Deciding what will render controller output

Tags: web2py

On [this page](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/3#Startup) we read:

> If you do not write a view, the dictionary is rendered by
>   "views/generic.html"

This comment is made with respect to the file `default/index.py` but the problem is that there is an HTML file `default/index.html` AND [earlier in the text](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/3#Say-my-name) it was stated:

> When an action returns a dictionary, web2py looks for a view with the
>   name `[controller]/[function].[extension]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is, but that first statement is not with respect to `default/index.py`, which doesn't exist. Rather, it refers to the `index()` function in the default.py controller, which is in the /controllers folder. It is simply stating that *if* there is no /views/default/index.html view, then the dictionary returned by the `index()` function will be rendered by the /views/generic.html view. In other words, web2py will first look for a /views/default/index.html view, and if that view does not exist, it will fall back to /views/generic.html (note, this is only if response.generic_patterns is set appropriately -- for more see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10#Generic-views)).